# JSON parsing not working as expected in Java

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have done JSON parsing earlier but this one is not working for me. I don't know why. It's a quite simple structure still I am not able to fix it.

Here is the response that I am getting from my URL.

```
{
    "BalanceItems" : [{
            "BalanceItem" : {
                "BalanceType" : "General Cash",
                "Description" : "Prepay Credit",
                "ShortDescription" : "Your bal is $",
                "Value" : 187.95,
                "Unit" : "$NZ",
                "ExpiryValue" : "",
                "ExpiryDate" : "18\/02\/2012"
            }
        }, {
            "BalanceItem" : {
                "BalanceType" : "Me 2 U",
                "Description" : "Me2U Credit",
                "ShortDescription" : "Your bal is $",
                "Value" : 176.86,
                "Unit" : "$NZ",
                "ExpiryValue" : "176.86",
                "ExpiryDate" : "12\/06\/2011"
            }
        }, {
            "BalanceItem" : {
                "BalanceType" : "Rate Plan Recharge Reward",
                "Description" : "Your 'top up and get' special rates",
                "ShortDescription" : "Your 'top up and get' rates are yours until",
                "Value" : ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code

```
try{

            URL url = new URL("myurl");         
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();   

            String line;   
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();   
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); 

           while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {    
               builder.append(line);   
           }   

           String response = builder.toString();   

           JSONObject jar = new JSONObject(response);
           Log.e("Object Size","Object Size  "+ jar.length());
           // Here i should get the size of object as 3 because i have three object of type "BalanceItem"

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

Comment: Post your Logcat, errors, your code and then people will try to help you.

Comment: What does your code for parsing the JSON look like?

Comment: Actually, `jar.length()` is 1. It contains only `BalanceItems` array. JSONArray BalanceItems length should be 3.

Comment: if i am not wrong here BalanceItems is an Array and BalanceItem are object. so how can i get the BalanceItem object and get its values.

Comment: Sujit, please edit your question with your code.

Comment: Hi NickLarsen i am getting this response {"BalanceItem":{"ShortDescription":"Your bal is $","BalanceType":"General Cash","ExpiryDate":"18\/02\/2012","Value":187.95,"Description":"Prepay Credit","ExpiryValue":"","Unit":"$NZ"}} for obj ........but              for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i); 
      Log.d ("Balance "+i, obj.get("ShortDescription") + " " + obj.get("BalanceType")); 
     
   } i am getting No value for ShortDescription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a JSON object that contains a JSONArray. You need to get the JSONArray:

```
JSONArray array = jar.getJSONArray("BalanceItems");
Log.e("Object Size","array Size  "+ array.length());
```

Check the API here:

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

---

**Addendum:**

The array in turn contains several JSONObjects. You need to iterate through it and get each one:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
  Log.d ("Balance "+i, obj.getString("Value") + " " + obj.getString("Unit")); 
}
```

You get the idea. Typed in here on top of my head, so beware of the typos.

Comment: Hi Aleadam , thanks for your reply but how can i get all the values inside BalanceItem like BalanceType, Description etc.

Comment: each BalanceItem is a JSON object itself. I'll add some more detail to the answer

Comment: Please, help me to help you: describe how it is not working, so I understand what needs to be fixed. To start, tell me what do you get with `jar.toString()`

Comment: Aleadam. I have added my code below your code and also added the URL i am using . i need all value to be parsed . i don't know why it is not working.....

Comment: Tell me the outputs of `Log.d ("test", response);` (right after String response = builder.toString();) and  `Log.d ("test2", jar.toString());` (after JSONObject jar = new JSONObject(response);)

Comment: response of test : 
{"BalanceItems":[{"BalanceItem":{"BalanceType":"General Cash","Description":"Prepay Credit","ShortDescription":"Your bal is $","Value":187.95,"Unit":"$NZ","ExpiryValue":"","ExpiryDate":"18\/02\/2012"}},{"BalanceItem":{"BalanceType":"Me 2 U","Description":"Me2U Credit","ShortDescription":"Your bal is $","Value":176.86,"Unit":"$NZ","ExpiryValue":"176.86","ExpiryDate":"12\/06\/2011"}},{"BalanceItem":{"BalanceType":"Rate Plan Recharge Reward","Description":"Your 'top up and get' special rates","ShortDescription":"Your 'top up and get' rates are yours until","Value":""}}]}

Comment: response of test2:{"BalanceItems":[{"BalanceItem":{"ShortDescription":"Your bal is $","BalanceType":"General Cash","ExpiryDate":"18\/02\/2012","Value":187.95,"Description":"Prepay Credit","ExpiryValue":"","Unit":"$NZ"}},{"BalanceItem":{"ShortDescription":"Your bal is $","BalanceType":"Me 2 U","ExpiryDate":"12\/06\/2011","Value":176.86,"Description":"Me2U Credit","ExpiryValue":"176.86","Unit":"$NZ"}},{"BalanceItem":{"ShortDescription":"Your 'top up and get' rates are yours until","BalanceType":"Rate Plan Recharge Reward","Value":"","Description":"Your 'top up and get' special rates"}}]}

Comment: That looks good. So what is the error? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: i just want to get all values in the object BalanceItems nothing else.i am trying it but not working in my end.

Comment: Well, for the last time: **What do you mean by "not working"?** Do you get some error? You don't get the right output? WHAT?

Comment: I am not getting any error . I just want to know how can i get all the value of BalanceItems by iterating in a loop. Thanks.

Comment: use obj.getString(label) as I used in the example, with the rest of the labels. I used only two as an **example**. Just do the same with the rest. Please, take the time to read the website I linked. You will understand much better how to implement all JSON parsing then.

Comment: can you tell me this. why the log is not getting printed on logcat here.... JSONArray array = jar.getJSONArray("BalanceItems");
     Log.e("Object Size","array Size  "+ array.toString());
     
     for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
      Log.d ("Balance "+i, obj.getString("ShortDescription") + " " + obj.getString("Unit")); 
   }

Comment: response for array.tostring()...[{"BalanceItem":{"ShortDescription":"Your bal is $","BalanceType":"General Cash","ExpiryDate":"18\/02\/2012","Value":187.95,"Description":"Prepay Credit","ExpiryValue":"","Unit":"$NZ"}},{"BalanceItem":{"ShortDescription":"Your bal is $","BalanceType":"Me 2 U","ExpiryDate":"12\/06\/2011","Value":176.86,"Description":"Me2U Credit","ExpiryValue":"176.86","Unit":"$NZ"}},{"BalanceItem":{"ShortDescription":"Your 'top up and get' rates are yours until","BalanceType":"Rate Plan Recharge Reward","Value":"","Description":"Your 'top up and get' special rates"}}]

Comment: @Sujit read also this very nice tutorial. It will be very helpful: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Comment: BTW, I believe we need to extract one more object. Replace `JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);` with `JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("BalanceItem");`

Comment: Thanks for you help Aleadam....Now its working fine. Now i need to understand the control flow . Thanks again..